# dotted outline coming for <button> tag in firefox

Tags: html, firefox

On focusing of the `<button>` tag, I'm unable to remove dotted border around its text.

I tried

```
border:0, outline: 0
```

properties. These properties only remove border and outline from `<button>` but border around text comes on focusing of button.

Here is my fiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/souviksarkar86/4shqvaq8/`

Comment: This worked. Thanku:)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```